# Decompression error when file was copied via ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am copying a gz zipped csv file from SFTP location to blob via ADF and using compression option of dataset while copying as shown below:
[image]

But receiving below error:

ErrorCode=InvalidDataFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=**The source data has an invalid format. Cannot decompress the source data.** Source file name: '1.csv.gz'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.SharpZipBaseException,Message=Unexpected EOF,Source=ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib,'

Also tried to unzip that file using winzip tool and facing below error:
[image]

But when i directly download the file from SFTP and unzip it, the file gets unzipped properly.

Any idea why only receiving this decompression error when file is getting copied via ADF?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is like “1.csv.gz” , and Compression Type selected is “.gz” as below, then pipeline will fail:

[image]

Pipeline Copy activity shows error Invalid File format:

[image]

**Solution**: Once Compression Type is selected as “ZipDeflate” as shown below for the Copy Data Activity Source dataset:

[image]

Pipeline executes successfully:

[image]

Output in ADLS with csv files:

[image]

[image]